# passing static values to a pdo insert block, failing

Tags: php, pdo

i have a sql insert statement that inserts into 6 table columns. the last two are using predefined values. in the values part of the sql statement i just put the values in within quotes(and it worked in the tutorial im following)  but it wont work. i removed the last two values and columns in the sql statement and it inserted them fine so for some reason its not taking the static values. can anyone spot the problem?

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $name = $_POST["commenterName"];
  $email = $_POST["commenteremail"];
  $comment = $_POST["commenterthoughts"];
  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Dublin");
  $currenttime = time();
  $datetime= strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", $currenttime);




    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(datetime,name,email,comment,approvedby,status) VALUES(:time,:name,:email,:comment,'pending','off')";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':time',$datetime);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name',$name);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':comment',$comment);
    $Execute = $stmt->execute();



    if($Execute){
      $_SESSION["success"] = "data added successfully";
      redirect("fullpost.php");
    }else {
      $_SESSION["error"] = "something went wrong. data not added to table";
      redirect("fullpost.php");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does it tell you when you enable error reporting?

Comment: error reporting is enabled, not getting any errors. i used var_dump on the $execute statement and it printed out bool true

Comment: it is unlikely that the statement would silently not insert the row. how do you know the error reporting, **and** displaying of errors, are enabled? you did it the php.ini? add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` right before the if.

Comment: i have the following at the top of the page ```<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); // set to false in production
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>```

Comment: Great! Sorry for making you repeat yourself, sometimes question askers don't have it right... So yeah, that is correct, now sometimes PDO will not actually throw the errors, when creating the PDO object do you set the error mode? look here https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php to do it

Comment: no need to be sorry and thanks for your time. im just wondering where do i include the setattribute in my code? in the example on that page it puts it with the db connection, but i already know mine is working

Comment: you could add `$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` just before the `$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);` line, or right after `$connect = new PDO(/**/);`, right when you create `$connect`

Comment: still no errors for some reason. is there anything wrong with the way im passing the static variables in the values part of the sql? i have triple checked the column names their definately correct

Comment: never mind i have it sorted wasnt anything to do with the sql statement it was my redirect part. thanks for your help mate at least now i know how to set pdo errors

Comment: Heh, glad you could solve it. cheers.